# Get current logged in user in Django forms

Tags: python, django

I need to get the current logged in user in Django form. I need it to get the domain from his email and accordingly fetch the list of other users with similar domain. Here is my code so far:

**forms.py**

```
class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):

    choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        self.user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(i.id, i.email)
                                                                   for i in User.objects.all()
                                                                   if not i.is_active and
                                                                   self.user_email in i.email
                                                                   ])
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def auth_users(request):
    form = auth_users(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/auth_users.html', context={'form': AuthUserCheckbox()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the request's user into your form constructor and then place that form in `context`. Your view needs to look something like:

```
@login_required
def auth_users(request):
    form = AuthUserCheckbox(request.POST, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/auth_users.html', context={'form': form})
```

Of course, the above is an incomplete view, because you shouldn't just grab POST like that, but that is not the question.

Comment: You saved my day ! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Yeah I'll be working on the POST data. The emails with the matching domain as that of the logged in user will be used later in the view.